# AWS VPC for Glue Job accessing SOAP API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-vpc

I am just getting started with AWS. I am building an AWS Glue script that connects to a given SOAP API and downloads response data (in XML) and saves to S3.

My question is - do I need to setup VPC with subnet, IP (private/public) etc on AWS for the Glue job to work i.e. connect to the SOAP API and extract data ? I searched a lot over the internet but didn't find a concrete answer. If VPC is indeed required, then please suggest some resource which would help me configure the same on AWS for the Glue job to work.

Please let me know if additional information is required about my question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The VPC configuration is not needed, as AWS Glue by default has normal internet access, because it's using default VPC that is managed by AWS for you.

So as long as your SOAP API is accessible through internet, it should work fine.

However if your API is accessible only in a private network, then you need to make sure, that AWS Glue has assigned correct VPC that is a part of that network, including correct VPC Security Groups.

If your API is accessible only using private network, then if it's possible I would recommend to make it available over the internet and for example get credentials for it using AWS Secrets Manager

### But how to implement that?

Since the logic for calling SOAP API would require some custom Python/Scala code (depends which runtime of Glue you are using), it might get complicated, as adding external libraries is additional work.

To abstract the Glue runtime from SOAP API, I would recommend using following design:

- implement your custom logic in Lambda function
- grant correct access to Glue IAM role to invoke that function
- invoke the Lambda from your Glue code (there is an example how to do that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50542986/6639950)

Probably you just want to fetch some data in a single or a few different ways, so it's in my opinion the best way to do it. Thanks to this you can use your runtime of choice in Lambda and easily develop that, including using custom libraries for SOAP API calls.

Comment: thank you.. do i need any specific connection in my Glue job to access the SOAP API ?

Comment: just updated the answer, take a look into if it makes sense :)